# Injectivity radius bounds for Riemannian manifolds of low regularity

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In their seminal [paper](http://Finite%20propagation%20speed,%20kernel%20estimates%20for%20functions%20of%20the%20Laplace%20operator,%20and%20the%20geometry%20of%20complete%20Riemannian%20manifolds), Jeff Cheeger, Mikhail Gromov, and Michael Taylor derivated bounds on the injectivity radius of Riemannian manifolds with bounded sectional curvature of the form:
$
inj(p)\geq r \frac{Vol(B_M(p,r))}{Vol(B_M(p,r)) + Vol(B_{T_p(M)}(0,2r))}
.
$
Their paper assumes that the involved manifolds are of $C^{\infty}$-type.

Since then, has anyone derived refinements/extensions for manifolds of lower regularity; i.e.: $C^k$ for some $1\leq k<\infty$?

Comment: Which estimate did you mean? Anyway usually there is no difference --- you can even assume that curvature is bounded from both sides in the sense of Alexandrov. So formally speaking there is no smoothness assumption altho it is $C^{1,1}$ or so.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I added the volume estimate the question.  Ah, I figured since I couldn't see a smoothness obstruction below $C^2$ (or I guess $C^{1,1}$) but still the issue is that I would need a reference which states this; and does not set-up in $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Yes, the same proof works in nonsmooth case --- there is no difference. Still, you should specify the curvature bounds --- I assume they are  $|sec|\le 1$ + I assume that r is small enuf, say $r<1$.

Comment: Instead of reference you may say "smooth using Ricci flow, apply the theorem and pass to the limit as time $\to0$".

Comment: Thought, still, a reference would be ideal since my audience are applied mathematicians and not geometers (so its less obvious to them and I don't have space left to re-derive this variant).